# Bing Maps V8 with React loading default map

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, loading, bing-maps

One part of my application has a map section that I don't won't to load automatically. Therefore I'm loading the Bing Map SDK in the map component with a Lazy load in the parent component. The problem is that the getDefaultMap function is being called before the SDK is fully loaded. I found a hacky solution but I'm sure that there is a better one. Basically the dependencies keep updating in my useEffect until there is the global variable Microsoft that comes from the SDK being fully loaded and it works as intended.

```
const [libraryLoaded, setLibraryLoaded] = useState(0)

const getDefaultMap = () => {
    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map("#myMap", {
      center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(37, -96),
      zoom: 4.5,
    })
  }

const addLibrary = () => {
    let script = document.createElement("script")
    script.src =
      "http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=bing_api_key"
    script.async = true
    script.defer = true
    document.body.appendChild(script)
    script.onload = () => {
      setLibraryLoaded(1)
    }
  }

useEffect(() => {
    if (libraryLoaded) {
      try {
        getDefaultMap()
      } catch {
        setLibraryLoaded(libraryLoaded + 1)
      }
    } else {
      addLibrary()
    }
  }, [libraryLoaded])
```

How I tried to solve it:

I tried calling the function after script.onload. I also tried removing script.async

```
const addLibrary = () => {
    let script = document.createElement("script")
    script.src =
      "http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=bing_api_key"
    script.async = true
    script.defer = true
    document.body.appendChild(script)
    script.onload = () => {
      getDefaultMap(()
    }
  }
```

I also tried adding the script tag like in the Bing documentation that included a callback parameter

```
<script
        type='text/javascript'
        src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=bing_api_key&callback=getDefaultMap'
        async
        defer
      ></script>
```

also tried with template literals

```
<script
        type='text/javascript'
        src=`http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=bing_api_key&callback=${getDefaultMap}`
        async
        defer
      ></script>
```

also tried with onLoad

```
<script
        type='text/javascript'
        src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=bing_api_key'
        async
        defer
        onLoad={() => {
          getDefaultMap()
        }}
      ></script>
```